# Recursive fibonacci sequence using stack pointer

Tags: assembly, recursion, stack, mips

I'm studying for a Computer Systems final and we're expected to have a strong grasp of recursion and for certain programming questions, to use the run-time stack to pass all parameters, return the result of the main program and to stack all variables that the subroutine uses to protect the main program.

The program I'm writing for practice recursively calculates a Fibonacci sequence. I understand how the subroutine will use the stack to receive arguments/parameters from the main program but I'm having difficulty understanding how it will use the stack as its method of returning the result to the main program, and when/how to stack all variables to protect the main program. Additionally, I'm having difficulty understanding how to implement the recursion portion.

I'm really looking for pointers on understanding the stack pointer, when/how to use it, how to implement recursion, and as a result, where I've gone wrong in my code and general pointers for my coding in MIPS. Thanks! The following is what I have so far:

```
.data
prompt: .ascii "This program calculates Fibonacci sequence. Enter non-negative number:"
result: .asciiz "F="
newline: .asciiz "\n"

.text
.globl main #defining starting point
main:

li $v0, 4   #print string
la $a0, prompt
syscall

li $v0, 5   #read in int
syscall

move $t0, $v0   #putting int into temporary register

move $a0, $t0   #put int as first argument
subi $sp, $sp, 8 #setting up stack
sw $zero, 4($sp)  # for return
sw $a0, 0($sp)    #push int onto stack
jal fibonacci

lw $t0, -4($sp) #get result from fibonacci

li $v0, 4   #print F=
la $a0, result
syscall

li $v0, 1
move $a0, $t0
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, newline
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall

fibonacci:
lw $v0, 4($sp) #load parameters
lw $a0, 0($sp)
beqz $a0, zero  #if n =0 return 0
beq $a0, $1, one # if n=1 return 1

#calling fib(n-1)
subi $sp, $sp, 4
sw $ra, 0($sp) #push return address onto stack

sub $a0, $a0, 1 #n-1
subi $sp, $sp, 8
sw $zero, 4($sp)
sw $a0, 0($sp)   #pushing n-1 onto stack
jal fibonacci    #fib(n-1)

lw $v0, -4($sp) #get result of fibonacci
add $a0, $a0, 1  #increment back our value

lw $ra, 0($sp) #restoring return address from stack
lw $a0, 4($sp) #protect main program by putting stuff back
sw $v0, 8($sp) #put result on stack

#calling fib(n-2)
subi $sp, $sp, 4
sw $ra, 0($sp)
sub $a0, $a0, 2 #n-2
subi $sp, $sp, 8
sw $zero, 4($sp)   #pushing n-2 onto stack
sw $a0, 0($sp)
jal fibonacci

lw $v0, -4($sp)
addi $a0, $a0, 2
lw $ra, 0($sp)  #restoring return address from stack 
lw $a0, 4($sp)  #protect main program by puttting stuff back
sw $v0, 8($sp)  #put result on stack

lw $s7, 0($sp)  #pop return value from stack (from f(n-1)
add $v0, $v0, $s7  #f(n-2) +f(n-1)
addi $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra 


zero:
li $v0, 0
lw $ra, 0($sp)      # Get return address
lw $a0, 4($sp)      # Protect main program by putting stuff back
sw $v0, 8($sp)      # Put result on stack
addi $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra

one:
li $v0, 1
lw $ra, 0($sp)      # Get return address
lw $a0, 4($sp)      # Protect main program by putting stuff back
sw $v0, 8($sp)      # Put result on stack
addi $sp, $sp, 12
jr $ra
```

Comment: _"how it will use the stack as its method of returning the result to the main program"_ That sounds like a strange approach. Typically you'd use `$v0` (and in some cases, `$v1` as well) to return the value of a function.

Comment: @Michael yeah it's odd, but it's what is included in the instructions. Is there anything else you could see that's wrong in my code?